# RecentApps does not show my app when only my app is in it

Tags: android, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I have an app that does not show when I try to resume it from the RecentApps button. This problem only occurs when there is only one app in the list of recent apps. I cannot replicate the issue if there are other apps in the list.

Here is how I navigate to my activities:

```
Activity_A (Main and Launcher, noHistory=true)
    ||
    \/
Activity_B (noHistory=true)
    ||
    \/
Activity_Main
```

`Activity_Main` is where I press back button. I catch the `onBackPressed()` and do some processing in a separate thread. If successful, I call `super.onBackPressed()` to exit the app else nothing happens.

I am running on Android Lollipop (v5.1.1). Am I missing something? Probably an Android bug? I can provide source code if needed.

Thanks and keep safe everyone!

Answer (score 2):

If you have this line:

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

in your `AndroidManifest.xml` then try to remove it or set it to false and let me know if it helps.

Comment: @user1506104 Then add this in your activity in manifest and set it to false.

Comment: It can be a bug in your android device, android studio or your project but I think there might a library which set this attribute to true in your projects `Merged Manifest` but anyway, I am happy to help you.

Comment: Hi there. Just to give you an update. I am removing this as the accepted answer. This worked for a moment. But upon testing again, the issue persists.

Comment: @user1506104 try run your app on another device and let me know.

Comment: Sorry I cannot test this on other devices as I am working on an app that only works on my special device that runs on Android Lollipop.

Comment: @user1506104 Search in your app's `Merged Manifest` for this line `android:excludeFromRecents="true` and let me know.